# Android set imageview programmatically without stretching

Tags: android

I am setting ImageView programmatically to create header for ListView ..

```
     ImageView imgView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_v_order);
     list.addHeaderView(imgView);
```

but it fits the whole screen header, i don't want to stretch it.. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use it as `backgroundResource` because background fills the whole space:

```
 ImageView imgView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
 imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_v_order);
 list.addHeaderView(imgView);
```

use it as `imageResource` it will show image of the size it is:

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_v_order);
```

and to align it in center without scaling use:

```
imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

Try using :

```
mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

explaination:

```
ScaleType.CENTER : Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling
```

If you use `FIT_CENTER`

`FIT_CENTER`:   Scale the image using [CENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER).

What `CENTER` does is:

```
public static final Matrix.ScaleToFit CENTER
```

Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

Answer (score 0):

use `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `setImageResource` and `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER` instead